# apply user-defined format in excel 2007 vba

Tags: vba, excel

The excel 2007 format i am using is: `#,##0.00,,,_);[Red](#,##0.00,,,);"-"`

if is is possitive, i want the number to display in billions; if negative, in billions and in parentahis; if missing, "-".

It works fine with excel 2007. But when i tried to apply the format in vba, it did not work.

Please use the following numbers as example:

> -11467478
>   224785.66
>   -5579046
>   1904770.9
>   -14916968

The data type i used is variant. shall i use long?

my initial code is something like:

```
......
with worksheet
'cells(1,1) would be any of the above numbers
  .Cells(1, 1).NumberFormat = "#,##0.00,,,_);[Red](#,##0.00,,,);" - ""
end with
.....
```

I got an erros message `run-time error 13, type mismatch`

I even tried to decompose the format. but it still did not work.

i am quite new to vba. could anyone help me? 
......

Comment: If it is working outside vba, it should work inside. Try double qouting ` -` like this `""-""`,

Answer (score 2):

This will also work, the dash is one of the characters that don't need to be escaped...

```
"#,##0.00,,,_);[Red](#,##0.00,,,);-"
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use double `"` for the minus sign. I tested your values and I think it should be:

```
.NumberFormat = "#,##0.00,,,_);[Red](#,##0.00,,,);""-"""
```

[image: customNumberFormat]